# Why isnt the jquery anchor tag scroll working?

Tags: jquery

Im trying to use some jquery to scroll some content on a portfolio gallery. The code im using i found on another site and allows the user to click the yellow arrows to scroll each project one at at time with anchor points however mine isn't allowing me to do that at the moment and im not sure why?

I've set up a JS Fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/b5X5w/2/

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to includ the [scrollTo](http://flesler-plugins.googlecode.com/files/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js) code in your jsFiddle. Once I did that the scroll part seemed to be working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b5X5w/5/).

[Here](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) and [here](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) are the two documentation pages for this plugin.

Comment: ah thanks pal. why does it seem to slide over to the right when its sliding down?

Comment: @DanFarrell If you only want the scroll on the y axis your call to `scrollTo` should look like this: `$.scrollTo({top: top, left: 0}, 500);`